# Logic Error Inserting Node in Linked List (Java)

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to learn to insert a node in a linked list (and return the head), but for some reason it is not correct.

This is my approach:

**1.** Create the new node with the desired data

**2.** If we want to insert it in the beginning, point this new node to the head and return the new node

**3.** Otherwise, loop to the position where we want to insert the node

**-** Once we get there, point the node to be inserted's next to the current node's next

**-** Point the current node to the node to be inserted

**-** Return the head

Why does this not work? Thanks so much!

```
Node InsertNth(Node head, int data, int position) {
    Node node = new Node();
    node.data = data;

    if (position == 0) {
        node.next = head;
        return node;
    }
    else {
        Node curr = head;
        int currPos = 0;

        while (currPos < position) {
            curr = curr.next;
            currPos++;
        }
        node.next = curr.next;
        curr.next = node;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean does not work? What's exactly happening? Please explain your problems; don't make us read code to figure it out.

Comment: At a high level code looks Ok, please let us know what issue you are facing.

Comment: Also, what does the call look like; is it `head = insert(...);`?

Comment: If you have a pointer to head in your datastructure, you have to update it.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you insert the new node after the `curr` node, this loop steps one node too far.

```
while (currPos < position) {
     curr = curr.next;
     currPos++;
}
```

You can easily work this out by stepping through through the code with a pen and paper, or with a debugger.

Answer (score -1):

If you insert the node to the Head you need to set the Head to the node you're inserting.

```
Node InsertNth(Node head, int data, int position) {
Node node = new Node();
node.data = data;

if (position == 0) {
    node.next = head;
    head = node;
}
else {
    Node curr = head;
    int currPos = 0;

    while (currPos < position) {
        curr = curr.next;
        currPos++;
    }
    node.next = curr.next;
    curr.next = node;
}
return head;
```

}

Comment: As per the algorithm shared, head is to be returned. That has been done in the if loop.

Comment: If you insert the node as the head, it return the head at the end of the method, pointing to the inserted node because, in the if loop we do `head = node;`

Comment: There is a return statetment inside if loop. It wont go to end of the method.   if (position == 0) {
        node.next = head;
        return node;
    }

Comment: You don't need the `return head;` inside the `if (position == 0)` because you're always returning the head. It's redundant. The difference is that if the position is 0, you're returning the new node as the head, and if the position is not 0 you're returning the same head.